# Instant App crashing when launching Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-instant-apps

I'm working to get my application compatible with Android Instant Apps SDK 1.0.0. My regular `app` module works just fine, no issues with Google Maps, or any other issues that I've found. However, whenever I try to test the Instant App module, the app crashes as soon as the maps try to initialize. Has anyone seen this or know what can be done to fix it?

```
06-20 11:10:57.263 13891-13891/com.myapp.example.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.myapp.example.debug, PID: 13891
                                                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
```

This is my build.gradle for the `appia` module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs '../libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {}
        debug {}
    }

    flavorDimensions rootProject.flavorDimensions

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }

        external {
            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':features:base')
    implementation project(':features:auth')
    implementation project(':features:lead')
    implementation project(':features:chat')
    implementation project(':features:search')
```

Comment: I have no issues converting the Google Maps samples to instant apps at https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples. Which device are you running on?

Comment: Are you even compiling `....play-services...`?

Comment: Please try again after updating to the latest libraries, currently at 11.0.4 https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases (related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089070/instant-app-crashing-on-adview-loadad-securityexception-failed-to-find-provide)

Comment: having same issue :/

Comment: @RyanInBinary i hope your problems has been solved with version 11.6.0.please can you confirm.

Answer (score 0):

[Identify tested compatible libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#identify_tested_compatible_libraries)

Following libraries supported for instant app.

- Google Play services location APIs
- Google Maps APIs

Always make sure you are using the latest library versions.

Please update to the latest version, it's currently at 11.6.0.

Comment: We have done that. We're actually working with your developer team on the issue. I received a support email on Tuesday confirming they have found the issue and are working to address it.

The issue is still present on 11.6.0.

Comment: yes, It would be great if you share complete details for testing platform and environment for more understanding. I hope it is problem in 8.0.Thanks.