# Instant app crashing on adview.loadAd, SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-instant-apps

I'm using play services ads 10.2.6 and it works just fine with the installed app.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1948)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1894)
        at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:768)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1924)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1913)
        at zh.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:7)
        at zh.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:84)
        at jg.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:14)
        at jf.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.clearcut.a.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ag.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl.newAdManagerByType(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.an.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:63)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ak.newAdManagerByType(:com.google.android.gms:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdManagerCreatorImpl.newAdManagerByType(:com.google.android.gms:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.aj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:32)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source:56)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzek$1.zzeI(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzek$1.zzeJ(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzek$zza.zzeR(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzek.zza(Unknown Source:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzek.zza(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzff.zzfj(Unknown Source:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzff.zzfi(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzff.zza(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source:0)
        at <activity_name>.loadAdView(<activity_name>.java:2416)
```

Comment: Can you try again with the latest library? 11.0.2 - 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20170629. Let me know if it solves it.

Comment: @TWL Thanks a lot, that solved it. Please write it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using play services ads 10.2.6

Always make sure you are using the latest library versions.

Please update to the latest version, it's currently at 11.0.2.

[Firebase Android Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20170629)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are existing issues based from this [GitHub post](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/26) and also filed in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121308). See if your encountered issue is related to any of these and follow the given workaround (if there is).

On a side note, since [`SecurityException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityException.html) crash is usually due to reading gservices without permission. You may want to also try [requesting permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).

If you haven't done so, note that on all versions of Android, your app needs to declare two categories of system permissions, normal and dangerous permissions, in its app manifest. Check [declaring permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html) for more information.

Comment: My question was edited by someone and they omitted the key word - "Instant App". I saw the links but I'm afraid they are not relevant.